# Comparing Summations & Frobenius Norms

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, summation, normed-spaces, frobenius-method

Given that $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$,and$$m_1=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i}||x_i-\mu||_2^2$$$$m_2=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{j}||x_i-x_j||_2^2$$
where $\mu=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i}x_i$

**I am trying to solve for whether $m_1=m_2$ or $2m_1=m_2$.**

Here's what I've tried:
$$m_1
=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i}||x_i-\frac{1}{N}x_i||_2^2 
=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i}||\frac{1}{N}(Nx_i-x_i)||_2^2
=\frac{1}{N^3}\sum\limits_{i}||(N-1)x_i||_2^2
$$
$$m_2=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{j}||x_i-x_j||_2^2$$

I do not know if my steps for $m_1$ is correct and how I should proceed with simplifying $m_2$ so that there's only summation with $i$ terms. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\bb{\mathbb}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\o{h}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\lr#1{\l(#1\r)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\lr{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Let $\{\e_k\}$ denote the standard basis for ${\bb R}^n$,
then given a matrix
$$\eqalign{
X &= \m{x_1&x_2&\ldots&x_n} \in{\bb R}^{m\times n} \\
}$$
we can calculate the following quantities
$$\eqalign{
\o &= \sum_{k=1}^n \e_k
   & \big({\rm all\,ones\,vector}\big) \\
I &= \sum_{k=1}^n \e_k\e_k^T
   & \big({\rm identity\,matrix}\big) \\
x_k &= X\e_k
   & \big(k^{th}\,{\rm column\,of}\,X\big) \\
\mu &= \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k 
 = \frac 1nX \lr{\sum_{k=1}^n \e_k} 
 = \frac 1nX\o \quad
   & \big({\rm mean\,of\,cols\,of}\,X\big) \\
M &= \m{\mu&\mu&\ldots&\mu} \;=\; \mu\o^T 
   & \big({\rm matrix\,of\,the\,means}\big) \\
\mu &= Me_k
   & \big(k^{th}\,{\rm column\,of}\,M\big) \\
\mu &= \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n \mu
 = \frac 1nM \lr{\sum_{k=1}^n \e_k} 
 = \frac 1nM\o
   & \big({\rm mean\,of\,cols\,of}\,M\big) \\
M:M &= \mu\o^T:\mu\o^T = \lr{\o:\o}\lr{\mu:\mu}
 = \c{n\lr{\mu:\mu}} \\
X:M &= X:\mu\o^T = X\o:\mu = \c{n\lr{\mu:\mu}} \\
}$$
where the colon denotes the matrix innner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
when applied to vectors, it corresponds to the vector inner product (aka dot product).

Now apply these ideas to your first sum
$$\eqalign{
\alpha &= \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i-\mu\|^2 \\
n\alpha &= \sum_{i=1}^n (X-M)\e_i:(X-M)\e_i \\
 &= (X-M)^T(X-M):\lr{\sum_{i=1}^n\e_i\e_i^T} \\
 &= (X-M)^T(X-M):I \\
 &= (X-M):(X-M) \\
 &= \lr{X:X} - 2\lr{M:X} + \lr{M:M} \\
 &= \lr{X:X} - n\lr{\mu:\mu} \\
\alpha &= \frac 1n\lr{X:X} - \lr{\mu:\mu} \\
}$$
Then to your second sum
$$\eqalign{
\beta &= \frac 1{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \|x_i-x_j\|^2 \\
n^2\beta
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n X(\e_i-\e_j):X(\e_i-\e_j) \\
 &= X^TX:\lr{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(\e_i-\e_j)(\e_i-\e_j)^T} \\
 &= X^TX:\lr{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \e_i\e_i^T - \e_i\e_j^T - \e_j\e_i^T + \e_j\e_j^T} \\
 &= X^TX:\lr{nI - \o\o^T - \o\o^T + nI} \\
 &= X^TX:\lr{2nI - 2\o\o^T} \\
 &= 2n\lr{X:X} - 2\lr{X\o:X\o} \\
 &= 2n\lr{X:X} - 2n^2\lr{\mu:\mu} \\
\beta &= \frac 2n\lr{X:X} - 2\lr{\mu:\mu} \;\doteq\; 2\alpha \\\\
}$$

---

**NB:** The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a colon product to be rearranged in many equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
A:BX &= B^TA:X = AX^T:B \\
}$$